# Style Parcolumns vertical bar

Tags: color, rules, parcolumns

How can I style the vertical bar in parcolumns that appears when using `rulebetween=true`?

I am trying to do something similar to what you can do with `\vrule` like the below:

```
\newcommand\VRule{\color{gray}\vrule width 0.5pt}
```

Here is what I have currently:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{parcolumns}% http://ctan.org/pkg/parcolumns
\begin{document}
    \begin{parcolumns}[nofirstindent,colwidths={1=2cm},rulebetween=true]{2}
        \colchunk[1]{\noindent 1770 }
        \colchunk[2]{\noindent \lipsum [1-3]}
    \end{parcolumns}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just patch the `\pc@placeboxes` command; be sure to provide a definition for `\VRULE`, however.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{parcolumns}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\pc@placeboxes}{\vrule}{{\VRULE}}{}{}
\makeatother
\newcommand\VRULE{\color{red}\vrule width 0.5pt}


\begin{document}

\begin{parcolumns}[nofirstindent,colwidths={1=2cm},rulebetween=true]{2}
\colchunk[1]{\noindent 1770 }
\colchunk[2]{\noindent \lipsum [1-3]}
\end{parcolumns}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This will alter every `\vrule` below the `\patchcmd` though correct?

Comment: @RyanGates Only every dividing rule produced by `parcolumns`. If you `\renewcommand{\VRULE}{...}` in between two such environments, you can change the appearance of it.

Comment: @HarishKumar I keep doing that mistake, thanks. :)